# Library or component for load usr web page in android

Tags: android, components, html, android-library

Is there a tool for loading a page `url` other than the WebView?

Thank you and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Is there a particular problem with `WebView` that you are experiencing?

Comment: webView is very slow in load my url

Answer (score 0):

No. A `WebView` is exactly what you should be using for this purpose.

Comment: i use webView. but this tool is very very very slow for load url while internet speed is good.